# How to stop a Flink job using REST API

Tags: jenkins, apache-flink

I am trying to deploy a job to Flink from Jenkins.  Thus far I have figured out how to submit the jar file that is created in the build job.  Now I want to find any Flink jobs running with the old jar, stop them gracefully, and start a new job utilizing my new jar.

The API has methods to list the jobs, cancel jobs, and submit jobs.  However, there does not seem to be a stop job endpoint. Any ideas on how to gracefully stop a job using API?

Comment: Probably an example required to understand what exact problem you have. actually flink should have stop command that is a more graceful way than cancel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though the stop endpoint is not documented, it does exist and behaves similarly to the cancel one.

Basically, this is the bit missing in the Flink REST API documentation:

> #### Stop Job
>
> `DELETE` request to **`/jobs/:jobid/stop`**.
>
> Stops a job, result on success is `{}`.

For those who are not aware of the difference between cancelling and stopping (copied from [here](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/setup/cli.html)):

> The difference between cancelling and stopping a (streaming) job is the following:
>
> On a cancel call, the operators in a job immediately receive a `cancel()` method call to cancel them as
> soon as possible.
> If operators are not not stopping after the cancel call, Flink will start interrupting the thread periodically
> until it stops.
>
> A “stop” call is a more graceful way of stopping a running streaming job. Stop is only available for jobs
> which use sources that implement the `StoppableFunction` interface. When the user requests to stop a job,
> all sources will receive a `stop()` method call. The job will keep running until all sources properly shut down.
> This allows the job to finish processing all inflight data.

Answer (score 0):

As i'm using Flink 1.7, below is how to cancel/stop flink job about this version.

**Already Tested By Myself**

- Request path:
  `/jobs/{jobid}`

  > jobid - 32-character hexadecimal string value that identifies a job.
- Request method: **PATCH**
- Query parameters:

  > mode (optional): String value that specifies the termination mode. Supported values are: "cancel, stop".
- Example
  `10.xx.xx.xx:50865/jobs/4c88f503005f79fde0f2d92b4ad3ade4?mode=cancel`

> host an port is available when start yarn-seesion
>
> jobid is available when you submit a job

Ref:

> https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.7/monitoring/rest_api.html`

Answer (score 0):

For Flink 1.19, if started with `./bin/start-cluster.sh`, Flink seems to require a normal GET request to `/jobs/<job id>/yarn-cancel` to cancel the job.

It doesn't seem to be documented. I found the API by looking at what the webui does when canceling my job.